# NgModel not getting bound in HTML - Angular9

Tags: angular, angular9

I have an angular ng-autocomplete dropdown field(https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ng-autocomplete), used in table.

```
            <div class="">
              <ng-autocomplete 
                [(ngModel)]="data.CC" [(initialValue)]="data.CC"
                [data]="CCData"
                [searchKeyword]="keyword" placeHolder="Select" (selected)='selectEvent($event)'
                name="testfield" 
                [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate" [notFoundTemplate]="notFoundTemplate">
              </ng-autocomplete>
              <ng-template #itemTemplate let-item>
                <a [innerHTML]="item.dispName"></a>
              </ng-template>
              <ng-template #notFoundTemplate let-notFound>
                <div [innerHTML]="notFound"></div>
              </ng-template>                  
            </div>
```

I have object array on which I am iterating the table data. The `[(ngModel)]` do not bind when the page load, but it quickly binds when I click on anywhere on page.
I also displayed the JSON data for the model and it holds the value, but do not bind when page load.I do not get any error.

When page loads it is as below: upper value is JSON which I displayed, I want same value in control field

[image]

Next when I click anywhere on page, it quickly binds value to control

[image]

I could not find why is such behaviour. Any input will be helpful.

Edit:

The complete solution is I have angular-calendar(https://angular-calendar.com/#/kitchen-sink) On date click I try to load calendar data and for the current day date the below grid is loaded automatically if data is present, it works for other controls but for ng-autocomplete it doesnt, it only works on click somewhere on page.
Ts code:

```
ngOnInit() {
var d = new Date();
this.selectedDate = this.locaDatePipe.transform(d, "yyyy-MM-dd");
this.month = d.getMonth();
this.tsData = {
  "data": [
    { "timeRecordId": 0, "stTime": "", "edTime": "", "efforts": "", "costCarrier": "", "description": ""}
  ]
};        
var event=[{"start": new Date(),
        "title": '',
        "meta": {               
          "stTime": "11:39",
          "edTime": "13:39",             
          "costCarrier": "4",
          "desc": "test3",              
        },
      }];
this.displayEvent(new Date(),ev);
}
       
displayEvent(date, events): void { 
for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
  this.tsData.data[i] = {
    "timeRecordId": events[i].meta.timeRecordId,
    "stTime": events[i].meta.stTime, 
    "edTime": events[i].meta.edTime,                
    "description": events[i].meta.description, "systemName": events[i].meta.systemName,        
    "costCarrier" : this.getFilteredCodes(this.costCarrierData, "costCarrierId", events[i].meta.costCarrier)[0].dispName,                
  };
}
```

}

var `event` format is in accordance with angular-calendar,so that data bind to calendar as well.

Comment: change detection cycle runs only when you click somewhere. show us your `.ts` code where you set the model.

Comment: @micronyks added the .ts code, pls check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not probably an answer but I was able find and alternative to above problem, I used primeng autocomplete https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/autocomplete in place of ng-autocomplete, It has more easy implementation.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-autocomplete-demo